# The determinant of a two-variate version of Vandermonde matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Let $d\geq 1$ be an integer. Denote $n = \binom{2+d}{d}$ and let $(x_k, y_k), k =1,..., n$ be $n$ points in $[0,1]\times[0,1].$ Let now $M \in \mathcal{M}_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$ be the matrix whose $j$th row is given by

$$(M)_j= (1, x_j, y_j, x_j^2, x_j y_j, y_j^2,..., x_j^d, x_j^{d-1}y_j,..., y_j^d)^T.$$

For example,  for $d =2,$ we have
$$M =\left(\begin{matrix} 1&1&1&1&1&1\\ x_1&x_2&x_3&x_4&x_5&x_6\\y_1&y_2&y_3&y_4&y_5&y_6\\x^2_1&x^2_2&x^2_3&x^2_4&x^2_5&x^2_6\\x_1y_1& x_2y_2&x_3y_3&x_4y_4&x_5y_5&x_6y_6\\y^2_1&y^2_2&y^2_3&y^2_4&y^2_5&y^2_6\\\end{matrix}\right).$$

In many references, the transpose of $M$ is called the multivariate (here two-variate) Vandermonde matrix. I wonder if there is an explicit formula for the determinant, so that one can find the necessary and sufficient condition on the points $(x_k ,y_k)$ for which $M$ is invertible.

Thank you for any hint.